# An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Overflow

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void btnSubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Validation.accdb") + ";Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connParam);
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblClients (Firstname,Lastname, Phone,StreetAddress,City,Country, ZipCode) VALUES (@fname,@lname,@phone,@saddress,@city,@country, @zipcode)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saddress", address.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zipcode", zipcode.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Display.aspx");
    }
}
```

My insert works but when I press the submit button many times (I have validators to test whether or not my text boxes are well entered or missing text) the 'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();' gives an exception error. I don't know why, I'm new, therefore any tips would be helpful thank you.

Comment: What is the exact error? And also check to see if the column types and lengths are OK and set the same restrictions in the application so the data won't overflow.

Comment: What do you mean by "I press the submit button many times"? Is it (1) about pressing the button in rapid succession (insert estimated frequency here, like 10 times/sec) or is it (2) about pressing the button a large number (insert observed amount here, like 100 clicks) of times, even with more time between the clicks?